# Why does the SARS-Cov2 genome has letter t

Tags: genome, phylogenetics, rna, sars-cov-2, covid-19

`ATTAAAGGTT TATACCTTCC CAGGTAACAA ACCAACCAAC TTTCGAT...` is part of the 5'UTR of genome of an RNA virus SARS-Cov-2.

RNA contains letters `C`+`G`+`A`+`U`.
DNA contains letters `C`+`G`+`A`+`T`.

Why are there letters `T`, in the SARS-Cov-2 genome, instead of `U`?

Comment: This was also answered here: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/11353/why-does-the-fasta-sequence-for-coronavirus-look-like-dna-not-rna/11358#11358

Answer (score 10):

We sequence and therefore typically report assemblies as DNA sequences, even if they're actually RNA.